# can't access class variable python

Tags: python, class, variables

I'm building a desktop app with python and have some issues getting a class variable I set up.

My program is built like this:

CharCreator.py

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    charName = ""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def editCharClick(self):
        from CharEdit import editUi

        MainWindow.charName = self.getSelected()
        print(MainWindow.charName)
        if(MainWindow.charName is not None):
            self.editWin = editUi()
            self.editWin.show()
        else:
            print("charName is none")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I've got my main window class, with a charName class variable. 
Then I have the typical methods(init, main etc) and have an editCharClick method that takes the selected row of my table, gets the name of my desired cell and assigns its string content to my class variable.
This part works well in my CharCreator.py file.

The problem comes in my second file. As seen in my editCharClick method, it opens a second window (CharEdit.py file). That's where I need to get the MainWindow.charName class variable.

CharEdit.py

```
class editUi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(editUi, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("./ui/new.ui", self)

        from CharCreator import MainWindow
        print(MainWindow.charName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newwindow = editUi()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've simplified this file just to get my class variable right, yet can't seem to make it happen.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please explain why you are using a class attribute? Shouldn't it be am instance attribute?

Comment: Because when I create an instance of my mainwindow, a new mainwindow pops up and I didn't like that behaviour.

Comment: Usually you create one main window.

Comment: Thanks, if you think that could solve the problem I'll look into it. I'd rather avoid it though, since I'd have to refactor 2 different files and one of them has 8000+ lines of code.
Isn't there some way I could just grasp the class variable the way I was trying to?

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing my code to work with event/signals but didn't quite like it.
So I just went the easy way and changed the editUi class constructor so it would accept another argument.
Then, when creating the editUi object in MainWindow.editCharClick(), you can pass the variable in the editUi object as an argument.

CharCreator.py

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    charName = ""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def editCharClick(self):
        from CharEdit import editUi

        MainWindow.charName = self.getSelected()
        print(MainWindow.charName)
        if(MainWindow.charName is not None):
            self.editWin = editUi(MainWindow.charName)
            self.editWin.show()
        else:
            print("charName is none")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

CharEdit.py

```
class editUi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, ch):
        super(editUi, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("./ui/new.ui", self)

        from CharCreator import MainWindow
        print(ch)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    newwindow = editUi()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```